# python read and convert raw 3d image file

Tags: python, medical-imaging

I am working with ct scans medical images in raw format. It is basically a 3d matrix of voxels (512*512*nb of slices). I'd like to extract each slice of the file into separate files.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# reading the raw image into a string. The image files can be found at:
# https://grand-challenge.org/site/anode09/details/
f = open('test01.raw', 'rb')
img_str = f.read()

# converting to a uint16 numpy array
img_arr = np.fromstring(img_str, np.uint16)

# get the first image and plot it
im1 = img_arr[0:512*512]
im1 = np.reshape(im1, (512, 512))
plt.imshow(im1, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r)
plt.show()
```

The result definitely *looks* like a chest ct scan, but the texture of the image is strange, as if the pixels were misplaced.

[image]

Some relevant info might be located in the associated .mhd info file, but I'm not sure where to look:

```
ObjectType = Image
NDims = 3
BinaryData = True
BinaryDataByteOrderMSB = False
CompressedData = False
TransformMatrix = 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Offset = 0 0 0
CenterOfRotation = 0 0 0
AnatomicalOrientation = RPI
ElementSpacing = 0.697266 0.697266 0.7
DimSize = 512 512 459
ElementType = MET_SHORT
ElementDataFile = test01.raw
```

Comment: what do you mean 'misplaced'? It looks like an abdominal CT slice. Have you tried windowing the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
Dim_size=np.array((512,512,459),dtype=np.int) #Or read that from your mhd info File

f = open(FileName,'rb') #only opens the file for reading
img_arr=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.uint16)
img_arr=img_arr.reshape(Dim_size[0],Dim_size[1],Dim_size[2])
```

if you are Memory limited read the file in chunks

```
f = open(FileName,'rb') #only opens the file for reading
for i in range(0,Dim_size[2]):
    img_arr=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.uint16,count=Dim_size[0]*Dim_size[1])
    img=img.reshape(Dim_size[0],Dim_size[1])
    #Do something with the Slice
```

A good way to show what's actually in the raw- File would also be to read it in ImageJ. For reading such ITK compatible files, there is even a PlugIn available, but direct raw import should also work.
https://imagej.net/Welcome
http://ij-plugins.sourceforge.net/plugins/3d-io/